# how to wire a light with only 2 wires available?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, repair, outdoor

I have some outdoor lights that are broken and need replacing. I have bought some new ones which I thought were suitable. However the problem I have is only 2 wires appear from wall recess (active and neutral). The light fitting I bought has a 3 point connector (a point for active, neutral and earth). Can this light fitting be wired into the 2 existing wires, or does it need an earth wire?

Comment: Where in the world are you, and can you post a photo of the inside of the box?

Comment: I am in Australia

Comment: Can you post a photo of the box's insides?

Answer (score 1):

You only need two wires. The earth, or ground, wire is a safety measure should something go wrong with the wiring inside, exposing a live wire. Older homes don't even have such a thing throughout the home and often include a three prong electrical outlet through "updating" without wiring up the ground connection.

Comment: Don't jump to conclusions! We don't know how the OP's house is wired -- conduit jobs have turned up on this site on quite a few occasions, and we've seen armored-type cables show up in a few questions here too

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel You're right. I hadn't considered that cause it wouldn't be the norm.